# Problem with OhMyZsh installation

Tags: zsh

Basically, I was installing ohmyzsh on Ubuntu because I'm learning about terminals and personalization.

But when I finished the installation of the ohmyzsh, I think the root directory changed by itself, and I don't know how to fix this (sorry If I can explain properly, I hope the screenshot can help clarify the problem, the directory should be my user but it is not)

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] with `id ; pwd ; ls -la`